# Showing Terms and Conditions for first time in an android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

I am developing an android app in which the first screen is the splash screen. If the user is a first time user(meaning the app was just installed) I have to show the terms and conditions
otherwise, I have to show the login screen.

How to get the number of times the application was opened or an indication that the app is opened for the first time? Is there any `API` for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have this counter:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
if(!prefs.getBoolean(KEY_EULA_ACCEPTED, false)) {
    showEula();
    // Determine if EULA was accepted this time
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(KEY_EULA_ACCEPTED, true).commit();
}
```

Comment: Hi I have a small doubt. How is the comparison being done here. if EULA= false we are launching showeula or otherway around. Shared Preferences are really confusuing. Another doubt is getboolean is getting the preferences value then why we are mentioning false?

Comment: And I think we have to mention context for getDefaultSharedPreferences? I mentioned it with this keyword

Comment: `false` in `getBoolean()` means that if there's no such preference in the storage, this method will return 'false`. And I can't understand your first question.

Comment: And how can i share the preferences across different classes? I wanna access the same preference in another class

Comment: Then you do the same thing in other class. The only thing you need is the context.

Comment: and i think we need to use a string "eula" instead of KEY_EULA_ACCEPTED

Comment: It's kind a good coding practices to use variables instead of magic numbers and strings. So, there must be `public static final String KEY_EULA_ACCEPTED = "eula";` somewhere in you code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) ([tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)).

Just check for a certain value onCreate().  If it's not there, do something, then set the value.  Next time, the value will be there and you can skip it.