# How to make terms and condition page in android

Tags: android

tnc_fullscreen.xml
Buttons at the bottom is not displayed.
Code is not scrolllable.
Below is the code. 
Please tell me where i am going wrong

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background = "@drawable/black_background_metal">

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" 
             android:background="#3500ffff">
             <!-- This text is not scrollable-->
             <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView

                android:text="@string/TnC"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor = "#ffffff"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
```

This is scrollview not working

```
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/fullText"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/fullText"
                 android:textColor="#ffffff" />
         </LinearLayout>
```

This table layout is not displayed in UI

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

             <TableLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip" >
                <TableRow>
                   <Button
                    android:id="@+id/accept_button"
                    android:text="@string/accept_label" /> 
                    <Button
                      android:id="@+id/Dntaccept_button"
                      android:text="@string/Dntaccept_label" />

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <Button
                      android:id="@+id/GoToDisclamer_button"
                    android:text="@string/GoToDisclamer_label" />

                    <Button
                      android:id="@+id/Exit_button"
                      android:text="@string/exit_label" />   
                </TableRow>
               </TableLayout>
```

None of the buttons are visible

Comment: **theres a similar question have a look**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849076/showing-terms-and-conditions-for-first-time-in-an-android-app

Answer (score 0):

## try this xml

```
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:background="#3500ffff">
         <!-- This text is not scrollable-->
         <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView

            android:text="@string/TnC"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor = "#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/fullText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/fullText"
             android:textColor="#ffffff" />
     </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

         <TableLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip" >
            <TableRow>
               <Button
                android:id="@+id/accept_button"
                android:text="@string/accept_label" /> 
                <Button
                  android:id="@+id/Dntaccept_button"
                  android:text="@string/Dntaccept_label" />

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <Button
                  android:id="@+id/GoToDisclamer_button"
                android:text="@string/GoToDisclamer_label" />

                <Button
                  android:id="@+id/Exit_button"
                  android:text="@string/exit_label" />   
            </TableRow>
           </TableLayout>
```

Comment: This is not valid xml